# Null response from instrument on starting app from Appium

Tags: appium

Appium version: Version 1.4.8
Mac OSX: 10.10

On starting the Appium server and launching the Appium inspector, the simulator is booting but the app is not loaded.

Trace below: 
Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":false,"valid":false,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},">":[]}}}

The inspector loads up with only a single element: UIAAplication

P.S: The app loads perfectly with the Xcode Simulator

Comment: I have the same problem as you, did you find a solution ?